# How do I implement a unidirectional one to many self referencing relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, self-reference

I have a "Question" entity that I can persist to "Question" table. A question can have multiple translations. A translation is just another question in another language that is associated with its parent question with parent_id field. Thus the Question table has columns question_id (int), parent_id (int), language (varchar), prompt, etc. In my design, the parent_id is the same as the question_id for a translation. For example, let's say I have question with id 13 and 17 in English (default) and question 13 has 3 translations, in Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. Then the Question table would look like the following:

question_id parent_id language

13 13 English; 14 13 Chinese; 15 13 Japanese; 16 13 Korean; 17 17 English

In the Question object, I want map a Question's relation to its translations which is a @OneToMany self-referenced relationship. I have implemented it the following way after doing some research:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Question parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Question> translations;

    Other properties...
    Getters and setters....
}
```

However, I do not understand the following due to it being a self-referencing relationship:

- Is this a unidirectional or bidirectional relationship?
- What would the effect be of the annotation cascade = CascadeType.PERSIT on "parent" field or what does it mean in this case?
- Is it possible to replace the "parent" field with Integer "parent_id" and still maintain the relationship? In other words, can I just keep track of the parent with Integer "parent_id" instead of having the entire Question object like I have now:  private Question parent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Is this a unidirectional or bidirectional relationship?

What you have is self-referential **bidirectional** relationship. It is justa a special case of standard bidirectional relationships.

> - What would the effect be of the annotation cascade = CascadeType.PERSIT on "parent" field or what does it mean in this
>     case?

In this case and following your example, it means that if you set the `parent` 13 in your Question 14, just invoking persist for Question 14 the Querstion 13 will be persisted too.

I encourage to see the JPA specification to know what to expect (here is [JPA 2.1 spect](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)).

> - Is it possible to replace the "parent" field with Integer "parent_id" and still maintain the relationship? In other words, can I
>     just keep track of the parent with Integer "parent_id" instead of
>     having the entire Question object like I have now: private Question
>     parent

Yes, you could do the following replacements,

```
//@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
//@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
//private Question parent;
@Column(name="parent_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer parentId;

//@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
private Set<Question> translations;
```

Some notes about,

- Cascade persist option for `translations` collections isn't necessary. Due to the relationship isn't bidirectional anymore, you can add Questions 14, 15 and 16 to the Question 13's collection and persist it along with its collection.
- In a common scenario the `parentId` attribute will be updated when a question is add or move it to some collection (this fire up an update statement to set value of field `parent_id`). It shouldn't be necessary to modify the attribute manually therefore I add and set the `insertable` and `updateble` options to *false*.

Comment: First of all, thank you for responding. Setting the insertable and updatable options on parentId attribute do not seem appropriate here. I need to set the parentId when I add a new question. I am doing the following when I add a new Question but the parent_id in the database is null after the add operation: \n 'int questionId = questionService.addQuestion(question);
      question.setParentId(questionId);
      questionService.editQuestion(question);'

Comment: What I mean is, if the relationship is unidirectional (as the code I posted) you just need to add the new translation to the parent's collection. Instead of this, you can remove the `insertable` `udatable` option for set the parentId as you want. Edit the question post, add the code that isn't working please. (In your comment looks like are associating the question to itself)

Comment: I am associating the question to itself by assigning the question_id to parent_id. Thus the check question_id==parent_id being true means this question is a parent and can have translations. I guess could leave the parent_id null for this kind of question, more of a design choice. Anyways, would you know how to make it so that a question with one or more translations can't be deleted? Can I enforce this through JPA annotations or will this need to be handled in the database, in this case in MySQL? Thanks

Comment: I don't know if there is a JPA annotation for this... If you set the foreing key on your database the JPA provider will rise an exception (rollingback the transaction) due to the constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to separate the question from the translation, create a Question entity:

```
@Entity
public class Question {
  private int id;
  //other independent translation properties
}

@Entity
public class QuestionTranslation{
  private int id;

  @ManyTone
  private Question question;
  private Language language;
  private String translation'
  //more translation based info
}
```

This way, you dont need the complication between parent, child stuff.